# Why are not all Salesforce users showing up in Linkedin Sales Navigator?

Tags: integration, permissions, user

I have 3 sales employees that we have assigned seats to in the Sales Navigator Team from Salesforce. I was able to click on the "Assign Seats from CRM" button and it showed me the list of Salesforce users. However one of our sales employees doesn't show up in that list. They have a salesforce account with the same role and Profile as the other 3 employees. This employee also has a Linkedin account like the other 3. Every other Salesforce user is showing up on the drop down list except for that one sales employee.

What permission or role is required to have users show up in the "Assign seats to your Salesforce users" drop down list in Linkedin Sales Navigator?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Related to LinkedIn, I would contact their support